# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service-docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium

I am facing issues on running the below selenium tests on docker container.
Code:

```
package docker;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class DockerDemoClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities().chrome();
URL url=new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
RemoteWebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url,dc);
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzwnM13Na8E");
System.out.println("Title is"+driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'd9d51ea0ffc4', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'd9d51ea0ffc4', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-KVPE3B65', ip: '172.20.32.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
remote stacktrace: [{fileName=DriverServiceSessionFactory.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory, lineNumber=194, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=DriverServiceSessionFactory.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory, lineNumber=67, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=SessionSlot.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot, lineNumber=145, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=LocalNode.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=newSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode, lineNumber=362, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=startSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor, lineNumber=624, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=newSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor, lineNumber=550, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=handleNewSessionRequest, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable, lineNumber=797, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=lambda$run$1, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable, lineNumber=758, classLoaderName=app}, {fileName=ThreadPoolExecutor.java, moduleVersion=11.0.15, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=runWorker, className=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor, lineNumber=1128, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=ThreadPoolExecutor.java, moduleVersion=11.0.15, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=run, className=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker, lineNumber=628, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=Thread.java, moduleVersion=11.0.15, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=run, className=java.lang.Thread, lineNumber=829, classLoaderName=null}]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at docker.DockerDemoClass.main(DockerDemoClass.java:16)

Comment: Please provide your docker container setup - issue is there

Comment: are you mentioning the .yml file?

Comment: Yes, whatever you use to start docker container.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Selenium docker container setup is wrong. Please verify with [official documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium). Most probably you've forgotten to add `--shm-size="2g"` . See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#--shm-size2g) for full explanation

Comment: Where should I add --shm-size="2g"?

Comment: The provided documentation suggests one of the docker container commands that enables shm: `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.3.0-20220628`

Comment: Super.. This is really helped for me